# Gradius-like game

Tags: c++, game

I have some experience with OOP but I'm very new to game programming. For a  school assignment, here's my first attempt at making a "real" game containing Entities, a game engine, game loop and the likes. I wanted to know if I used those concepts correctly, and would love to have some tips on things I could've done better.

[GitHub](https://github.com/wburgos/ft_retro)

Here's the `Entities` header, from which everything is derived (players, enemies, asteroids...):

```
#ifndef A_ENTITIES_HPP
# define A_ENTITIES_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>

class AEntities
{
private:
    AEntities(void);

protected:
    WINDOW const *      _win;
    int                 _x, _y;
    int                 _winwidth, _winheight;
    char                _char;
    AEntities *         _missile;

public:

    AEntities(WINDOW const * win, int x, int y, char caract);
    virtual ~AEntities(void);
    AEntities(AEntities const &src);

    AEntities &operator=(AEntities const & rhs);

    virtual void        movement() = 0;
    virtual void        update(void) = 0;

    void                draw(void);
    void                del(void);

    bool                impact(AEntities * entities) const;

    int                 getX(void) const;
    int                 getY(void) const;
    char                getChar(void) const;
    AEntities *         getMissile(void) const;

    static int          loopCount;
};

#endif
```

And here's the `GameEngine` which contains a array of pointers to `Entities`, for their management:

```
AEntities *                 _entities[ENTITIES_MAX];
```

Code:

```
#include "GameEngine.hpp"

GameEngine::GameEngine(void)
{
    initscr();
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);
    getmaxyx(stdscr, _winheight, _winwidth);
    _p1 = new Player(stdscr, 0, _winheight / 2);
    _win = stdscr;
    for (int i = 0; i < ENTITIES_MAX; i++)
        _entities[i] = 0;
}

GameEngine::~GameEngine(void)
{
    delete _p1;
    endwin();
}

GameEngine::GameEngine(GameEngine const &src) :
_win(src._win), _winheight(src._winheight), _winwidth(src._winwidth)
{
}

GameEngine      &GameEngine::operator=(GameEngine const &src)
{
    if (this != &src)
        _win = src._win;
    return (*this);
}

bool                GameEngine::render(void)
{
    usleep(15000);
    mvprintw(0, 0, "Score: %d", _score);
    if (AEntities::loopCount == 101)
        AEntities::loopCount = 0;
    AEntities::loopCount++;
    if (rand() % GameEngine::i < 5)
    {
        int enY = rand() % _winheight;
        addEntity(new Enemy(_win, _winwidth, (enY == 0) ? 1 : enY));
        if (GameEngine::i == EASY)
        {
            int asY = rand() % _winheight;
            addEntity(new Asteroids(_win, _winwidth, (asY == 0) ? 1 : asY));
        }
    }
    if (!updateEntities())
        return (false);
    drawEntities();
    refresh();
    return (true);
}

AEntities *         GameEngine::getEntity(int n) const
{
    return (_entities[n]);
}

void                GameEngine::drawEntities(void)
{
    _p1->draw();
    for (int i = 0; i < ENTITIES_MAX; i++)
    {
        if (_entities[i] != 0)
            _entities[i]->draw();
    }
}

void                GameEngine::addEntity(AEntities * entity)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ENTITIES_MAX; i++)
    {
        if (_entities[i] == 0)
        {
            _entities[i] = entity;
            return ;
        }
    }
}

bool                GameEngine::updateEntities(void)
{
    _p1->del();
    _p1->update();
    addEntity(_p1->getMissile());
    // _p1->draw();
    for (int i = 0; i < ENTITIES_MAX; i++)
    {
        if (_entities[i])
        {
            _entities[i]->del();
            _entities[i]->update();
            // _entities[i]->draw();
            addEntity(_entities[i]->getMissile());
        }
    }
    if (playerColision())
        return (false);
    entityColision();
    return (true);
}

void                GameEngine::deleteEntity(AEntities * entity)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ENTITIES_MAX; i++)
    {
        if ( _entities[i] == entity)
        {
            if (_entities[i])
                delete _entities[i];
            _entities[i] = 0;
            return ;
        }
    }
}

bool                GameEngine::playerColision(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ENTITIES_MAX; i++)
    {
        if (_entities[i] && _p1->impact(_entities[i]))
            return (true);
    }
    return (false);
}

void                GameEngine::entityColision(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ENTITIES_MAX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < ENTITIES_MAX; j++)
        {
            if (_entities[i] && _entities[j] && _entities[i]->impact(_entities[j]))
            {
                _score += 50;
                deleteEntity(_entities[i]);
                deleteEntity(_entities[j]);
            }
        }
        if (_entities[i] && (_entities[i]->getX() < 0 || _entities[i]->getX() > 3000))
        {
            _score -= 10;
            deleteEntity(_entities[i]);
        }
    }
}

WINDOW const *      GameEngine::getWindow(void) const
{
    return (_win);
}

int         GameEngine::i = EASY;
int         GameEngine::_score = 0;
```

PS: The graphical part is handled with ncurses, but really, all there is to it is `mvaddch(y, x, char)`, which draws a `char` at the specified position (yes, y first). Also, the `GameEngine::i static` thing for managing difficulty wasn't made by me, and it could indeed be improved by at least passing it to a `GameEngine` constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One remark regarding the way collisions are handled:

```
bool playerColision(void);
void entityColision(void);
```

Basically what you want to do when you have a generic game engine is the possibilty to reuse your code, instead of having a distinction between "Player" and "AEntities" inside your GameEngine, your GameEngine could only handle "AEntities" entities and having a callback to call in the AEntity class

```
void OnCollision(AEntity* other);
```

This way each class could handle the collision the way they want.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, dimmark111. Glad to have you, and this answer. Enjoy the site!

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have already covered some architectural aspects, so this review is going to be on coding style mostly.

1. Avoid exposing unnecessary dependencies in a header file. In the `AEntities` header file, you don't need `<iostream>`. Put that in the `.cpp`s only if you need it.
2. Variables starting with an underscore are somewhat contrived in C++ land. Your usage of such naming is not conflicting with the standard, but I'd still suggest that you steer clear of this notation. [Read this very good answer posted on StackOverflow for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654).
3. Don't write `void` in the parameter list of a function that takes no arguments. Unlike in C, both `T func(void);` and `T func();` mean the exact same thing in C++: a function taking 0 arguments. So adding `void` is pure boilerplate and adds nothing to the better understanding of the code.
4. Picking a little in your type naming, `AEntities` sounds wrong to me. The class is supposed to represent one entity, I figure, so why the plural name? And also, why the `A` prefix? `Entity` or `GameEntity` would read much more logically and nicer.
5. Again picking on naming, the variable that holds the game difficulty is called `i`? I mean, seriously? `i` is historically used as name for loop counters, using it for anything else is bound to generate confusion. Not to mention that in this case it is impossible to guess that `i` is actually the `difficultyLevel`. Can you change that? Please do so if you can. Also, a plain `int` seems deficient for it. Perhaps an `enum` would be better, then you could have predefined constants like `Easy`, `Medium`, `Hard`, `Nightmare`, etc...
6. In your implementation of `GameEngine`, what's with all the space between the return type and name of methods?

   > ```
   > bool                GameEngine::render(void)
   > //  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Why all this again?
   > ```

   That's a huge waste of horizontal spacing.
7. `return` is not a function, so there is no reason to do add parentheses, besides the love for typing. I used to do this myself, now whenever I look at old code all I think is: why the heck did I do this everywhere?...

   > ```
   > return (true);
   > //     ^    ^
   > //     |    |
   > //   don't need
   > ```
8. The implementation of `GameEngine::operator =` seems very questionable. It only copies the `_win` member. What about the rest? But should a game instance be at all copyable? Perhaps you should take a look at [**The Rule of Three/Five/Zero**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and rethink this.
9. I see that you are using some raw pointers here and there. Manual memory management is a rare thing to see in user code nowadays. It is considered an outdated practice in face of standard containers and [**smart pointers**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory). Memory erros make up for some of the hardest bugs to track down and memory leaks are very easy to introduce when doing manual allocations/deallocations. For your `_entities` array, a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) would be a cleaner choice and with it you could even lift the `ENTITIES_MAX` constraint (`vector` can grow dynamically).
10. You have a few "magic numbers" in `entityColision()`, such as `3000`, `50` and `10`. Hard to guess what they mean. Comments would help, named constants with descriptive names would be perfect.

Comment: First of all thank you for this detailed answer.
1. I include iostream to have std::string available in my header, and since the cpp uses it aswell, it's 2 birds with a stone.
4. The 'A' prefix stands for 'Abstract' so I know at first glance that this classe can't be instanciated and one should only work with derived classes.
5. Yeah I know, this part wasn't made by me and I didn't agree with it either but forgot to change it.

Comment: 6. The spaces provides a alignment with all my declaration, so I can use the multiline cursor feature of Sublime Text pretty nicely :) also I find it more readable.
7. I think those parentheses make the whole returned expression much more readable, but that's just me.
9. Since it was a school asignment we had some constraints, mainly regarding the use templates unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, okay, so it is better to include `<string>` then. It is probably just a coincidence that `<iostream>` is pulling `std::string` with it. That might break on some other compiler. Humm, I didn't realize that the `A` meant abstract. The `I` prefix is actually somewhat common for "interface" classes. [See this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/117348/should-interface-names-begin-with-an-i-prefix)

Comment: @Willy, about the spacing and such, don't take that too literally, it is a subjective matter. I merely mention it to plant the seed of doubt `;)`

Answer (score 3):

I see some speedups but the optimizer probably already handles them. Still, it's good programming practice to move things out of loops when possible

I notice in `entityColision()` you delete an entity upon collision, which prevents it from participating in any other collisions. So, stop checking!

```
void                GameEngine::entityColision(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ENTITIES_MAX-1; i++)
    {
        if (_entities[i])
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ENTITIES_MAX; j++)
            {
               if (_entities[j] && _entities[i]->impact(_entities[j]))
               {
                   _score += 50;
                   deleteEntity(_entities,i);
                   deleteEntity(_entities,j);
                   goto NEXT_I; // no point checking any others
               }
            }
            int ix = _entities[i]->getX();
            if (ix < 0 || ix > 3000)
            {
                _score -= 10;
                deleteEntity(_entities,i);
            }
        }
NEXT_I:
    }
}

void                GameEngine::deleteEntity(AEntities * _entities, int i)
{
    if (_entities[i])
    {
        delete _entities[i];
        _entities[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

so you don't have to search for something when you already know where it is.